# How can I run chkdsk on boot up for multiple drives in Windows (Vista)?

Tags: windows, boot, chkdsk

I know how to run a `chkdsk` on boot for `C:`.

How can I schedule chkdsk to run on boot for multiple drives (which normally will just be checked inside Windows)?

Answer (score 9):

```
fsutil dirty set <drive:>
```

[From Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil_dirty.mspx):

> Queries to see whether a volume's dirty bit is set. Sets a volume's
>   dirty bit. When a volume's dirty bit is set, autochk automatically
>   checks the volume for errors the next time the computer is restarted.